# Any option include nuget packages to common class library and other project will resolve it automatically [VS 2017]?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, nuget-package, class-library

I have a scenario where I have 20 class libraries referencing same NuGet packages and everytime whenever I need to update new NuGet version I require to update into all 20 projects.

So do we have any option where I can include NuGet packages into a common library and other projects will resolve it out of the box.

Any help appreciated.

Note: I am using .Net Framework Project and not core.

Comment: If your 20 projects are part of one solution (.sln), can't you just Manage Nuget Packages for the entire solution and update all projects in the same time ?

Comment: Yes, but it will add the change in all 20 projects. So I am looking for an option where I can make the change into a common library and others will resolve automatically.

Comment: If you create a nuget package that has references to all these external packages, then yes, it will work.  That's how the majority of nuget packages work.